# Show only posts which can be commented

Tags: comments, pre-get-posts

I have a pre_get_posts filter to show exclude some posts on the homepage. But I can't exclude the posts which are closed for commenting. How do I do this?

What I have is:

```
function wp_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
// Only modify when on homepage & only the main query
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'comment_status', 'open' );
        $query->set( 'tag__not_in', '188' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '3' );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wp_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

Excluding the post from category 188 works fine, but excluding the posts with closed comments does not. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `comment_status` is not a built-in query argument - but you can easily implement it:

```
function wpse_214323_query_by_comment_status( $where, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! empty( $wp_query->query_vars['comment_status'] ) ) {
        $status = $wp_query->query_vars['comment_status'];

        if ( $status !== 'open' )
            $status = 'closed';

        $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.comment_status = '$status'";
    }

    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_214323_query_by_comment_status', 10, 2 );
```

Use this in addition to your existing code, now you can query `'comment_status' => 'open/closed'`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm. If anyone else needs it a little more info:
Add the code from TheDeadMedic and add to your `wp_filter_pre_get_posts`:  `$query->set( 'comment_status', 'open' );`

Comment: One more question: I am trying to add the possibility for exceptions – to show certain posts for which the comments are closed nevertheless. I tried: `function wpjj_filter_sticky( $query ) {
     $meta_query = array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
   array(
    'key' => 'show_aways',
    'value' => 'yes',
    'compare' => 'EXISTS'
   ),
   array (
    'comment_status' => 'open'
   )
  );
  $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpjj_filter_sticky' );` But it will only show the posts with the meta, not the open posts.