# Show only posts which can be commented OR have custom meta field

Tags: custom-field, comments, pre-get-posts

I'd like to exclude posts on the homepage which are closed for comments. This works thanks to this: [Show only posts which can be commented](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214330/63639)

Now I'd like to add the possibility for exceptions – to show certain posts for which the comments are closed nevertheless. They are marked with a custom field "show_always".

I tried:

```
function wpjj_filter_sticky( $query ) { 
  $meta_query = array( 
    'relation' => 'OR', 
    array( 
      'key' => 'show_aways', 
      'value' => 'yes',
      'compare' => 'EXISTS' 
     ), 
     array ( 
       'comment_status' => 'open'
     )
   ); 
   $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query ); 
} 
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpjj_filter_sticky' );
```

But it will only show the posts with the meta, not the open posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets try the following:

By default, all posts are returned regardless of `comment_status`, so lets run the main query as normal, that is, query all posts regardless of `comment_status`.

We will also run a small, but very lean secondary query where we will get all posts which have

- a `comment_status` of closed
- which have a meta value of not `yes`

The returned ID's will then be passed as `post__not_in` to the main query to exclude these posts

I think this is a better approach because handling SQL which involves meta queries yourself can get really messy, specially when you start adding complicated nested meta queries. Let `WP_Query` handle the `meta_query` part for us.

We will still use the `comment_status` parameter which is supported by the custom filter by @TheDeadMedic in your linked question

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_home()
         && $q->is_main_query()
    ) {
        // Run our secondary query to get the posts to exclude
        $args = [
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,
            'comment_status'   => 'closed',
            'meta_query'       => [
                'relation'     => 'OR',
                [ // Compensate for posts which have the custom field set but not set to yes
                    'key'      => 'show_always',
                    'value'    => 'yes',
                    'compare'  => 'NOT IN' // Get posts which value is not yes
                ],
                [ // Compensate for posts which does not have the custom fields
                    'key'      => 'show_always',
                    'compare'  => 'NOT EXISTS' // Get posts which value is not yes
                ]
            ],
            'fields'           => 'ids', // Return only post ID's
            'suppress_filters' => false, // Allow the comment_status filter
            // Any other parameters
        ];
        $exclude_ids = get_posts( $args );

        // Now we can exclude the ID's we just queried
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', $exclude_ids );
    }
});
```

### EDIT

The above code is now tested and working as expected

### EDIT from comments

@birgire has filed a new trac ticket (*[trac ticket #35601](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35601)*) to enquire why `comment_status` is not available in `WP_Query` by default. Lets hope that we will see this incorporated into core in the near future. As soon as that happens, the custom filter will not be needed anymore

Comment: I'm not sure why `comment_status` isn't avialable in `WP_Query`, so I created a ticket [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35601) to hopefully shine some light on that.

Comment: @birgire it is quite strange as `comment_status` already is in the `wp_posts` table. I hope something like this gets accepted into core. Holding thumbs ;-)

Comment: That was quick, committed to core in only few hours after the ticket was created, thanks to Boone Gorges.

Comment: @birgire I've been following the trac ;-). See that implementation is set for 4.5. That was really quick. Congrats, that will save a lot of custom coding and extra filters

Comment: You guys are amazing!! Pieter, thank you so much for your solution—works perfectly! @birgire Thanks for the ticket—this was lightning fast!

Comment: @benutzerfreund glad it worked. Be sure to look out for the release of 4.5, the `comment_status` parameter should be available in which case you can drop the custom filter. Enjoy ;-)